Services in bundle-specific services.yaml are not loaded, even though imported correctly
I'm developing a bundle in Symfony 6.4 and defining my services in a bundle-specific services.yaml file located at /src/xxxBundle/Resources/config/services.yaml. This file is correctly loaded via the YamlFileLoader.
However, the services from this bundle-specific services.yaml are not being loaded correctly. When I move the same configuration to the standard /config/services.yaml, everything works fine.
The fact that the bundle-specific services.yaml file is being loaded and processed is evident because other sections like parameters: are processed correctly. If I deliberately create a syntax error, I get the corresponding error message.
Example configuration:
services:
    App\XxxBundle\Service\XxxService:
        arguments:
            $params: '@parameter_bag'
            $test: 'bla'


Error message:
Cannot autowire service "App\XxxBundle\Service\XxxService": argument "$test" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "string", you should configure its value explicitly.


If I move the configuration back to /config/services.yaml, it works again.
Directory structure:
src/
└── XxxBundle/
    ├── Controller/
    ├── DependencyInjection/
    │   └── XxxExtension.php
    ├── Resources/
    │   └── config/
    │       └── services.yaml
    ├── Security/
    └── XxxBundle.php

In the config/bundles.php file, I have the following entry:
App\XxxBundle\XxxBundle::class => array('all' => true),


Has anyone encountered this issue before and can suggest why it only works when I move the configuration into the standard services.yaml?
Steps I’ve already taken:

Cleared the cache multiple times (php bin/console cache:clear).
Verified that the services.yaml file is indeed being loaded.
Checked that the services.yaml file is syntactically correct.
The bundle is correctly registered in config/bundles.php.

Despite these steps, I get the error that the configuration from the bundle-specific services.yaml is not being processed correctly.

Symfony version? The Resources directory went away a long time ago. You tagged your question as Symfony 6 which implies a fairly recent version. I'd suggest running the make:bundle command just to see where what goes where and make sure you are not looking at old documentation.

In Symfony 6.4, the src/ folder is automatically created as part of the project structure, and it is common to use the src/ directory for local bundles. Additionally, the make:bundle command is no longer available in Symfony 6.4.
It appears that Symfony is ignoring all arguments in the services: section, even though the syntax is correct.

Hint: The file is being ignored even if the syntax is not correct. What does that imply to you? Not trying to be overly mysterious but again you are looking at old documentation and/or code.

"The fact that the bundle-specific services.yaml file is being loaded and processed is evident because other sections like parameters: are processed correctly. If I deliberately create a syntax error, I get the corresponding error message."
